# In the manga, what evidence did readers have about the identity of Miyu's brother?

Tags: fate-kaleid-liner-prisma-illya

Spoilers up to but not including the flashback arc in *3rei*:

> In the *Prisma Illya* anime, the fact that Miyu's brother is (Miyuverse) Shirou becomes obvious fairly early on. The scene early on in the first season ("1in"?) where Miyu mentions that Illyaverse Shirou reminds her of her brother already points strongly in that direction, as do the short still-frames of him we see in Miyu's memories during *2wei Herz*.
>
>  Early in *3rei*, Illya and Gil meet Miyu's brother, and though we don't get a clear visual on him, we hear Sugiyama Noriaki speak - that settles it for anyone who had any doubt.
>
>  However, I have heard that manga-readers weren't 100% sure about the identity of Miyu's brother until he shows up to fight the Ainsworths and utters "Trace On". I can see how this could be the case - if his appearance was better-concealed in the manga, that plus the fact that the manga is not voiced could have kept readers guessing for a while.

So - what evidence did manga-readers have about the identity of Miyu's brother prior to the definitive reveal?

Comment: This is a bit opinionated imo. Some readers are denser than others. One of the biggest hints was when Miyu first meet Illya's big brother,  almost mistaking him for her own by calling im onii-chan. Until the big reveal in Drei, no one can be certain of the identity until it is explicitly revealed. Hints are dropped, some more blatant than others. Sometimes in manga these hint are red herring, other times they are not. You can't be sure stuff like this.  Especially with Fate stuff.

Comment: @кяαzєя That's fair - what is or isn't obvious is a personal question. I guess my question is really more along the lines of "what evidence pointed towards the identity of Miyu's brother in the manga?".